# Search for text in some videos

Tags: video, search, text-search

I have some screen recordings of the game and want to search for some concrete text there (title of the mission). What program can I use to achieve that?

Can use it on Windows or Linux. Freeware is preferable.

Comment: This isn't a full elaboration of the stack, but you can use ffmpeg to split it into multiple frames (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917601/ffmpeg-split-avi-into-frames-with-known-frame-rate), use GNU Ocrad (https://www.gnu.org/software/ocrad/) to extract text, and then grep the output.

Comment: @HoldenRohrer, interesting idea, but seems very slow? Also I've expected that static text over dynamic video is simpler to recognize that to extract text from background on one of the frames, isn't it?